# How can I adjust image width and height to 100 x 100 keeping ratio?

Tags: css

Here's 2 images

1. width:300px, height:200px
2. width:200px, height:600px

I want both of these to be displayed as below

1. width:100px, height:66.6px
2. width:33.3px, height:100px

These are adjusted to the 100px mamimum keeping ratio.
How can I write in CSS?

Comment: Are you serious? I just want to set it minimum 100px at either width or height.

Comment: `width: 300px;` `height: calc(200/300*100)px;`

Comment: You only have to set max-width, or max-height. the image will scale preserving the ratio automatically. close this question NOW.

Comment: @HUSTEN Correction, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying a class like `.resize` below to your images should do what you want...

```
.resize {
    max-width: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rU5qK/

Comment: what if height: and width: are stated already? Your code will ignore them?

Comment: or do I need to take off height: and width: if it's stated?

Comment: @HUSTEN If you declare the width/height on the image element, eg: `<img src="" width="X" height="Y">`, this will cause odd/unwanted behavior with the above CSS. If you want to take advantage of an image's natural ratio (and use the CSS I outlined above) I would remove all declared width/height from the image elements.

Answer (score 1):

Use this...

```
image {
    width: 100px;
    height: auto;
}
```

Of course you can do `<img src="src" style="width:100px; height:auto;">` and changed width and height to `100px` accordingly.

Comment: But think about case 2. it will be taller than 100px then

Comment: @HUSTEN Change it to `height:100px;` and `width:auto;`